# How can I display the HTML content of a Text Area within a DIv AS HTML content and not text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have the following markup:

```
<input id="displayBuffer" type="hidden">
<textarea id="about" rows="2" name="about" cols="20" aria-hidden="true"><p>test</p></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:
$('#displayBuffer').val($('#about').html());
$('#displayAbout').html(unescape($('#displayBuffer').val()));"
 name="Preview" value="Preview">
```

When the 'preview' button is clicked the div is populated with the content of the 'about' text area however it is not being encoded as HTML but it's displaying `<p>test</p>` when I want it to display `test` with whatever style I have in CSS for `p`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should do it

```
$('your-container').html($('#about').val());
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/VY6Sh/2/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks mate, apparently my problem was that I was using .html() withthin the container's .html(). Using .val() as you suggested solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for placing content as html.

```
$('#show').click(function() {
    $('#Preview').html($('#about').val());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LCwgc/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea id="about" rows="2" name="about" cols="20" aria-hidden="true"><p>test</p></textarea>
<div id='displayAbout'>ale</div>
<input type="button" id='preview' name="Preview" value="Preview">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Buffer is useless:

```
$("#preview").click(function() {$('#displayAbout').html($('#about').val());});
```

Answer (score 0):

By HTML syntax, a `textarea` element must not contain markup, only text. You need a different approach, probably an element (e.g., `div`) with the `contenteditable` attribute.